# Are there special rewards for the temporary Hexakill gamemode?

Tags: league-of-legends

Some temporary gamemodes have special rewards like summoners icons.

**Are there special rewards for the temporary Hexakill gamemode?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there is 1 summoner icon for Hexakill on twisted treeline
(It takes up to 3 days before it can be used)

```
MARK OF THE BETRAYER ICON

Win three games of Hexakill: Twisted Treeline
```

With the harrowing event they also released some other icons

```
HARROWED PUPPET ICON

Give a gift of any kind to a friend before the Harrowing ends
```

And

> SHADOW ISLES CREST ICON
>
> Pledge your soul to the Shadow Isles for 1500 IP during the Harrowing,
>   or 250 RP any time afterward.

[Here](http://promo.euw.leagueoflegends.com/en/harrowing-2014/) is a link with all information about the harrowing event.